# Which machine learning classifiers to use for boolean, count and ratio features together?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-extraction, text-classification, naivebayes

Say I have names, geographic and gender information. And I want to create name and geographic features to predict the gender of a person.

The name features will be as follows:

1. 2-letter, 3-letter and 4-letter substrings, ie: Susan into 'su', 'us', 'sa', 'an', 'sus', 'usa'...
2. Entire name entities, ie: Susan Hay into 'susan' and 'hay'
3. Total name length, ie: Susan Hay into '8'
4. Non-ASCII character, ie: Susan Hay into '0'
5. Vowel-to-total length ratio, ie: Susan Hay into '3/8'
6. Location of residency, ie: Susan Hay into 'New York, U.S.'

I would like to use **Naive Bayes** classifiers to incorporate features 1-6 altogether as a feature set, but should I use the **Multinomial** or **Bernoulli** Naive Bayes?